# How to get Python bs4 to work properly on XML?

Tags: python, xml, unicode, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use Python and BeautifulSoup 4 (bs4) to convert Inkscape SVGs into an XML-like format for some proprietary software. I can't seem to get bs4 to correctly parse a minimal example. I need the parser to respect self-closing tags, handle unicode, and not add html stuff. I thought specifying the 'lxml' parser with selfClosingTags should do it, but nope! check it out.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from __future__ import print_function
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print('\nbs4 mangled XML:')
print(BeautifulSoup('<x><c name="b1"><d value="a"/></c></x>',
    features = "lxml", 
    selfClosingTags = ('d')).prettify())

print('''\nExpected output:
<x>
 <c name="b1">
  <d value="a"/>
 </c>
</x>''')
```

This prints

```
bs4 mangled XML:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.4.1-py2.7.egg/bs4/__init__.py:112: UserWarning: BS4 does not respect the selfClosingTags argument to the BeautifulSoup constructor. The tree builder is responsible for understanding self-closing tags.
<html>
 <body>
  <x>
   <c name="b1">
    <d value="a">
    </d>
   </c>
  </x>
 </body>
</html>

Expected output:
<x>
 <c name="b1">
  <d value="a"/>
 </c>
</x>
```

I've reviewed related StackOverflow questions, and I am not finding the solution.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980757/how-to-prevent-beautifulsoup4-from-adding-extra-htmlbody-tags-to-the-soup) addresses the html boilerplate, but only for parsing subsections of html, not for parsing xml.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844827/can-beautifulsoup-parse-xml-when-certain-tag-is-self-closing-and-not-at-the-same) pertains to getting beautifulsoup 4 to respect self-closing tags, and has no accepted answers.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211589/selfclosingtags-in-beautifulsoup) seems to indicate that passing the selfClosingTags argument should help, but as you can see this now generates a warning `BS4 does not respect the selfClosingTags argument`, and self-closing tags are mangled.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961497/how-to-get-beautifulsoup-4-to-respect-a-self-closing-tag) suggests that using "xml" (not "lxml") will cause empty tags to be automatically self-closing. This *might* work for my purposes, but applying the "xml" parser to my actual data fails because the files contain unicode, which the "xml" parser does not support.

Is "xml" different from "lxml", and is it in the standard that "xml" *cannot* support unicode, and "lxml" *cannot* contain self-closing tags? Perhaps I'm simply trying to do something that is forbidden?

Comment: “because the files contain unicode, which the "xml" parser does not support” → No, an XML parser *by definition* supports Unicode. You should post a minimal example of how you open and write the files.

Comment: Why not use lxml itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the result to be output as `xml` then parse it as that. Your `xml` data can contain unicode, however, you need to declare the encoding:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- encoding: utf8 -*-
```

> [The `SelfClosingTags` is no longer recognized](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#xml). Instead, Beautiful
>   Soup considers any empty tag to be an empty-element tag. If you add a
>   child to an empty-element tag, it stops being an empty-element tag.

Changing your function to look like this should work (In addition to the encoding):

```
print(BeautifulSoup('<x><c name="b1"><d value="a®"/></c></x>',
    features = "xml").prettify())
```

**Result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<x>
 <c name="b1">
  <d value="aÂŽ"/>
 </c>
</x>
```

Comment: Your encoding declaration declares the encoding of your source file. That is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @roeland: It's relevant, since without it any unicode characters within the XML will cause a syntax error. `Non-ASCII character: but no encoding declared`;  http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Comment: But the OP is loading the XML from SVG files.

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't have a way to include files with questions, so I can't make an SVG example, that's why we have the pure Python example.

Comment: @MRule: [https://gist.github.com/](https://gist.github.com/) works well for more detailed stuff — so you're not really limited to just posting the minimal example here. Then you can just provide a link to it within your question...

Comment: @MRule I think if you have a small example input file, it is OK to post the contents of that file in the question.