# BeautifulSoup can find xml node with lxml parser on Windows but not can not find on Linux

Tags: python, xml

I have a xml file, the content like

```
content ="""<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<passage>
  <title>Aggrecan Turnover</title>
  <author>Winsz-Szczotka K,Kuźnik-Trocha K,Komosińska-Vassev K,Jura-Półtorak A,Olczyk K</author>
  <source>Disease markers</source>
  <description>
   xxxxxxx
  </description>
  <filename>26924871.xml</filename>
  <passage_url>http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26924871</passage_url>
  <received_date>2016-03-02</received_date>
  <parameter_date>2016-02-29</parameter_date>
</passage>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "xml")
soup.find("author")
```

Result:

### On Windows:

```
<author>Winsz-Szczotka K,Kuźnik-Trocha K,Komosińska-Vassev K,Jura-Półtorak A,Olczyk K</author>
```

### On Linux

Nothing find,
When i change `<author>` node to `<author>Winsz-Szczotka</author>`, then it can find the node both Windows and Linux, So what make this happened?

Besides, when i change the parser to `html.parser` on Linux, it works well, i am confused, the content is xml format, why use html.parse work well?
anybody can tell me something, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that your XML file is properly UTF-8 encoded? Double-check. If you created it on Windows, chances are that it is actually not UTF-8, but some ANSI encoding. Use a HEX-editor to find out the byte encoding of the character `ź`, for example. It should be `0xC5 0xBE`. Is it?

Comment: The code works fine for me on Linux and returns the node as with your Windows example when I cut and paste (note I've done some tiny edits to make it cut and pasteable).

Comment: @Spacedman That's why I suspect a byte encoding error. If you copy the code off the web site, it will probably work fine.

Comment: @Tomalak it is  `<author>Winsz-Szczotka K,Ku\xc5\xbanik-Trocha K,Komosi\xc5\x84ska-Vassev K,Jura-P\xc3\xb3\xc5\x82torak A,Olczyk K</author> `on Linux, it seems like encoding error, but i don't know how to fix it, can you give me some advice? thx

Comment: ah, i try to use `soup = BeautifulSoup(content.decode('utf-8'))`, it work fine, thx, @Tomalak @Spacedman

Comment: Compare this question/answer and the comments below the answer, too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36144192/how-to-get-python-bs4-to-work-properly-on-xml

Comment: Generally, don't store any XML in your source code. Use separate files and file handles (`soup = BeautifulSoup(open("your.xml"), "xml")`) to parse them. Explicitly declare the XML byte encoding you are using`<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">`. UTF-8 is the default value. But explicit is better than implicit.